# Strange Cross inside TextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Have a problem with `TextBox`. If I set property `TextWrap` like `NoWrap`, I see a cross inside my `TextBox`. Can I delete or hide this cross?

[image]

**UPD:** Solution for my problem :

1. Set `TextWrap` like `Wrap`
2. I use `FontSize` 72px, and I set `Height` for my `TextBox` 72px.

And it will look like your `TextBox` without multiline and cross inside.

Comment: Please provide your code and maybe a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: @Sheridan I've walked him through this a couple times now, I think either the language barrier or skill level is obfuscating his actual question because otherwise it would have been solved by now lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cross is the `DeleteButton` that is built into the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209683) which if you look at it in that link and go to the bottom of the default template you'll see the `DeleteButton` `Button` at the bottom of the template. You can remove it there or the way I showed in the last post. :)

To get to the template (quickest way) is right-click your `TextBox` and choose "Edit Template" and then either edit a copy (which will put the template in your window.resources) and define it explicitly or edit the original template.

PS- You might add the image you had in your last post to this one for the viewers at home.

**EDITED FOR THE LOVE OF GOD AND SANITY**

Here dude, here's a copy of the default template with the button removed. Just put it in your UserControl.Resources, or Window.Resources, or Application.Resources, or just somewhere it can be found as a StaticResource.

```
    <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox 
         With the DeleteButton removed and given an explicit key name -->
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="LearningToEditControlsTodayYAY">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                                 To="0"
                                                                                 Duration="0" />
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                                 To="0"
                                                                                 Duration="0" />
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                                                        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                                                        Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                               Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                               FontStyle="Normal"
                                                               Text="&#xE0A4;"
                                                               FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                               AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Duration="0"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundThemeOpacity}" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Duration="0"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Duration="0"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBackgroundThemeOpacity}" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Duration="0"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBorderThemeOpacity}" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
<!-- ********************************
        SEE THIS, THIS IS WHERE IT'S TELLING THAT BUTTON TO SHOW ON THE "ButtonVisible" State,
        WHICH IF WE JUST COMMENT THIS OUT, MAKES IT GO AWAY. However I would also clean out the Button object and remove the unnecessary extra columndefinitions from the grid that holds it, but I'll leave that to you amigo....
***************************************** -->
<!--
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
-->
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                          Grid.Row="0"
                                          Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundHeaderThemeBrush}"
                                          Margin="0,4,0,4"
                                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                          FontWeight="Semilight" />
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                      VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                      IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                      IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                      IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      IsTabStop="False"
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                      ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      IsTabStop="False"
                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" 
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

<!-- *******************
     SEE THIS HERE, THIS IS THE BUTTON YOU WANT GONE
-->
                        <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then finally apply this style explicitly to your button like;

`<Button Style="{StaticResource LearningToEditControlsTodayYAY}"/>`

Comment: You removed the `Button` named "DeleteButton" from the template for `TextBox` and it didn't do it?

Comment: Ok that might work if you make `TargetType="Button"` not DeleteButton, an `x:Name` is not a `TargetType` amigo

Comment: Ok then just do it directly to the template and I guarantee it will work that way, can't always take the easiest route.

Comment: Ummm, where I can do this?) How I can change template?

Comment: See the part in my answer that says "To get to the Template (quickest way)" in the second paragraph?

Comment: Besides - you really don't want to remove the cross. It's there on purpose and if you remove it - you will make it harder for the user to clear the content of the `TextBox`.

Comment: See updated answer (read through the template also to understand more), I can't really make it any easier for you amigo. Also, @FilipSkakun has a point, but if it's your requirement, it's your requirement, eitherway I'm way past my usual 60second quota max for answering a question on here haha, cheers